# locate string in string and copy the substring onwards

Tags: multithreading, sockets, visual-c++

```
cstring str1="hello world!";
cstring str2="or";
```

I need to locate str2 in str1 and copy string "orld!" or "ld!"
but in my application, I dont know the content of str1.
could you help to figure out how to do this?

Comment: what is `cstring` did you try doing it yourself?

Comment: I see no relevance to multithreading or sockets in this question, so why the tags? What is cstring - do you actually mean the MFC CString? The question is unclear.